# Images circle (viewmaster like) with CSS3

Tags: css, gsap

I'm looking for something like [this](http://matthewlein.com/experiments/viewmaster/)
, but jQuery feels too much old fashioned.

Any examples for CSS3 equivalent?
Tweenmax examples may be even better..

Thanks.

Comment: You can use css `:target` but I don't know how you can do calculations with changing variables

Comment: JS will be used for the circle loop..

Comment: Than use css animations for the anmation when you click on an image and js for the rotation and position of the images on the circle

Comment: I'm looking for an example instead of writing it myself. Do you have any?

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/RotatingImageSlider/ . I know this is not what you want but it is the only good result if you search for a rotating slider

Comment: I found that I need to use css3 translate and rotate transforms, can someone tell me how to do the calculations with dynamic number of image (while the image dimensions are known)